# WiFi terribly slow minutes after boot

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I'm encountering a problem with the WiFi on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system. The issue is that the WiFi works fine right after boot but then drops to 1-2% of the initial speed minutes after.

On Windows 10 I don't have this issue.

I've tried `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` from this post [Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 20.04 is very slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243181/wi-fi-on-ubuntu-20-04-is-very-slow) which merely yielded the same results as a reboot.

I've got the ASUS ROG Strix X570-E Gaming motherboard with the Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 antenna. Also, I've been messing around with pwmconfig and fancontrol when the issue started but I'm not sure if that may be the cause.

Does anyone know how I could permanently fix this issue?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but maybe I'm still of help.

This issue has kept me tinkering for a few hours until I looked at the firmware provided by Intel. Last version for ax200 is -46 but kernel 5.13.0-35 loaded -63 which gave me problems.

Since I don't know how to force a specific firmware I just deleted every other iwlwifi firmware except iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode from /usr/lib/firmware and rebooted. WiFi works like in Windows now.