# Download speed very slow in Ubuntu 20.04.1 while upload speed is perfectly fine over wifi

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, internet

Im a new Linux user and I am facing this problem with my install. To be very specific, I have tried Ubuntu, Mint and even Kubuntu but this issue persists. The weird part is I am getting the exact same slow download speeds in all the distros which is 1.1Mbps (It should have been 45Mbps up+down) [checked through fast.com], but Im getting the full upload speed. [Using a fiber connection]

Things I have tried -

- Turning off the power management from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240386/1514484)
- Turning off IPV6 for that particular interface
- Updated grub and my system

Here is the output for

```
ip a

wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 192.168.1.47/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
   valid_lft 86044sec preferred_lft 86044sec 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is some information about my Network Controller

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 43f0 (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device 1652
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at 6205274000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Also

```
10.817111] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX203, REV=0x354
```

To add further, I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu as of now. The wifi works perfectly fine on windows 10.
So after trying everything else I tried to connect my phone to my wifi and then created a hotspot from my phone. I then connected my laptop[with Ubuntu] to that hotspot and it works perfectly fine.
The only issue is that I cannot keep doing this forever. Please help me out regarding this and do let me know if there is any command that i specifically need to check.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 20.04 is very slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243181/wi-fi-on-ubuntu-20-04-is-very-slow)

Comment: @24601 No sadly this doesn't solve the problem because my version is AX203 which is not available in this website (or maybe i am mistaken) https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Comment: Are you saying that WiFi works properly when using Windows, and that WiFi works properly when connected to a Hostspot? But WiFi does not work properly when connected to your router's WiFi? If true, then try rebooting your router.

Comment: @user535733 yeah i mean exactly that but like it works fine while using windows tho. In any case, let me try rebooting

Comment: Sounds like TKIP encryption being used on the router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright its totally my fault. The firewall on the router was set to strict and I changed it to be "low" and I'm getting the full bandwidth.
Anyways thank you for your time, guys