# Wi-fi is very slow on Ubuntu 22.04 despite Strong signal

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, 22.04, hp

I use Kubuntu dual booted with Windows 11 in my HP Victus 16. The Wi-Fi speed on Windows is fair enough. However, it is not the case with Ubuntu.

After doing some web searches, I followed this [Link](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) and this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243181/wi-fi-on-ubuntu-20-04-is-very-slow). I followed them accordingly, but it did not improve the situation.

Here is the output of `lshw -C network` command.

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 11
   serial: 38:87:d5:13:9b:ba
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-40-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.u ip=192.168.0.194 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:19 memory:6015224000-6015227fff
```

Here is my [wireless info script.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ct4MZkZZ99/)
Here is the output of the command `tail -f /var/log/syslog`: [syslog output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xsNxJzYrSg/).

As you see, the wireless card in my system is Tiger Lake PCH CNVi wi-fi. I tried looking for a solution with this keyword but could not find any.

Looking for help regarding this one.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit your question to include results from the wireless script

Comment: @waltinator, I have also tried that. Unfortunately, it does not work out for me, either.

Comment: @Jeremy31, I have updated it.

Comment: I would try `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` and see if it works better

Comment: @Jeremy31, thank you. It worked. But would you care to explain what happened behind the scenes?

Comment: Now do `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"| sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopts.conf` That commands enables aggressive TX that helps slow intel wifi

Comment: @Jeremy31, I already did that before you wrote. I had a query. Yesterday, I executed the same command except for the fact that it was disable=1. Why didn't it work back then? And how is boosting the internet speed? Please explain or share a link so I can get insights into it.

Comment: You can look at `modinfo -p iwlwifi` and see that 11n_disable=1 disables 11n functionality and that would make the connection slow and that setting to 8 enables aggressive TX

Comment: @Jeremy31, one thing to note is my wifi is still unstable. While the internet speed over the router's ethernet cable is decent, wifi's speed tends to be down at times (not always), given that I have made that change permanent. Do you have any idea whatsoever?

Comment: run this in terminal and edit the question to include results when wifi has issues `tail -f /var/log/syslog` use ctrl+c to quit the command when you have results

Comment: @Jeremy31, added. Please check. And thanks for your support.

Comment: Try `dmesg -w` and get results for a longer period of time

Comment: @Jeremy31, for how long to be specific?

Comment: Give it an hour or so, it might help to go into network setting and disable IPv6 for that wifi connection

Comment: For the time being, it is working fine. I could figure out that there are also issues with the router I am using; sometimes, there is packet blockage in the router. However, your provided solution was indeed helpful. Thanks.