# very low wifi network speed - ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, download-speed

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows two days back. I use "Free Download Manager" for downloads. I get about 5 mbps speed on windows but I get ~380 kbps to at most ~1 mbps. I also tried with two more download softwares - uget and jdownloader. Results are same.

Config:

```
uname -r
6.5.0-18-generic
```

Wifi:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280 
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
```

Driver:

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 5c:3a:45:12:12:2f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=6.5.0-18-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:160 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4200000-a420ffff
```

So far I have tried adding following options to lwlwifi.conf

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
```

I also changed the power options for wifi in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

The output of command `sudo ip l | grep $(ip r| awk '/default/ {print $5}')|awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'` is `wlo1: mtu 1500`. But I had changed that to 1492 as per [Wi-fi is very slow on Ubuntu 22.04 despite Strong signal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464538/wi-fi-is-very-slow-on-ubuntu-22-04-despite-strong-signal)

I also have disabled IPv6.

Despite, I still get very low speed.

What should I do to make it at least as good as Windows?